# How to run 64-bit Linux virtualization

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, 64-bit

Although this has been asked several times, the answers do not work on my system. Most of the answers are the same as in this post: [best answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1241956/virtualbox-only-allowing-32-bit-os).

In short: VirtualBox does not give me the option of running a 64-bit OS although (I think) my machine has the capability.

Things I have checked:

1. BIOS
2. Hyper-V (boxes are un-ticked)
3. CredentialGuard and DeviceGuard (not installed)
4. The CPU (this is the only part where I am unsure, screenshot below)

Settings and versions:

- Dell Latitude 7480
- Windows 10 (see screenshot)
- VirtualBox 5.1.26

[image: Windows OS]

BIOS (see screenshot):

- Virtualization Support

  - Virtualization (enabled)
  - VT for Direct I/O (enabled)
  - Trusted Execution (disabled)

[image: BIOS]

Hyper-V deactivated

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you run [Coreinfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo) and check if it lists a `*` next to "Supports … hardware-assisted virtualization"?

Comment: No, no star there @grawity:  
`Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz  
Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel  
Microcode signature: 0000004E  
HTT             *       Hyperthreading enabled  
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present  
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization  
SVM             -       Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization  
X64             *       Supports 64-bit mode`

Comment: Hmm, can you successfully _activate_ HyperV and set up a test VM in it? If it works, then you can probably conclude that the hardware/firmware is fine, and that HyperV hadn't fully disabled itself.

Comment: Thanks @grawity, I'll check it out. One of the IT experts here said there is a problem with emulating 64 bit virtualization without specific hardware which is possibly not in this machine. So the host can be 64 but not the guest. I'll try track it down but I think your first hunch was correct about the hardware-assisted virtualization!

Comment: "Specific hardware" might be an IOMMU, but you likely have that as well (your photo has a "VT for Direct I/O" section). There's really not much else to it.