# 64 bit host cannot have a 64 bit guest?

Tags: linux, cpu, 64-bit, vmware

I'm trying to run a 64 bit guest Linux installation with a Windows 10 Professional (x64) host.

I have an Intel i7-7700HQ. In my BIOS I made sure VT is enabled. HyperV is also enabled.

When I run VMware Workstation it tells me this processor cannot have a 64 bit guest.

1. How can I tell if my processor can or cannot have a 64 bit guest?
2. Is there any way to enable it, or am I forced to upgrade? If so, what processor would support this technology?

Comment: HyperV is supposed to be disabled; not enabled. That is what is preventing you from running a 64 bit guest at the moment.

Comment: oops the correct dupe should be [VirtualBox only allowing 32 bit OS](https://superuser.com/q/1241956/241386)