# I enabled vt-x but virtual box only shows 32 bit

Tags: virtualbox, 32-bit, vt-x

I am trying to run ubuntu 16LTS 64-bit on my computer but I come across some problems.

When I try to create a new virtual machine, I only get the option for 32-bit operating systems. All information I could find is that I need to enable vt-x and disable hyper-v. I did those two things, but the problem has not been resolved.

I run on an i7-6700k with ASUS PRIME Z270-P
I have never updated the bios, but it has the vt-x option, so I prefer not to update it to not break my PC.

What else could cause this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check in the BIOS if both VT-d VT-x are enabled.

Comment: @harrymc That was the solution. VT-x != VT-d. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox only allowing 32 bit OS](https://superuser.com/questions/1241956/virtualbox-only-allowing-32-bit-os)

Comment: Good that this is solved, so I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the BIOS to see if both VT-d VT-x are enabled

Both are required for VirtualBox to permit 64-bit VMs, and they are not the same
thing.

The full names by Intel are:

- Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d)
- Intel® VT-x with Extended Page Tables (EPT)