# Virtual box 6.1.26 Host Windows 7 64bit and VB only showing 32bit Windows VB available, how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am seeking to run a 64bit VB for a text environmen ton a blockchain. After downloading VB 6.1.26 it only give option of Windows 7 32 bit. I have an Intel processor. I read the BIOS settings can be changed to fix the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox only allowing 32 bit OS](https://superuser.com/questions/1241956/virtualbox-only-allowing-32-bit-os)

Comment: Additional duplicate [here](https://superuser.com/questions/866962/why-does-virtualbox-only-have-32-bit-option-no-64-bit-option-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

> VB 6.1.26 it only give option of Windows 7 32 bii

Start in BIOS and see if your computer supports Hardware Virtualization and Intel VT-d (VPRO is usually the advertised feature).

Not all computers support hardware virtualization.

Comment: Why did you not flag this question as a duplicate?

Comment: It has been flagged. I was not sure about about a specific duplicate.