# How do I enable VT-X on a Surface Book 2? WIN 10, i7-8650U

Tags: virtualbox, bios, virtualization, microsoft-surface

The processor is an Intel i7-8650U, [it supports vt-x](https://ark.intel.com/products/124968/Intel-Core-i7-8650U-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz).

You can boot into the "BIOS" by shutting down and then booting while pressing the volume up button; stop pressing once the Windows logo appears. However, in it there aren't any options to turn on vt-x.

I've gone to "Turn Windows features on and off" to verify that Hyper-V is not checked.

I'm trying to solve for this so that I can select Linux x64 in Virtualbox.

Comment: I'd guess that VT-x is enabled by default, but something else is already using it. Are you using Hyper-V, Docker, any Android emulators?

Comment: Aha! An Android emulator was taking over it, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I've posted that as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox - VT-x is being used by another hypervisor](https://superuser.com/questions/802669/virtualbox-vt-x-is-being-used-by-another-hypervisor)

Comment: Hyper-V was disabled for me. Check the settings in "Turn Windows features on and off"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that VT-x is enabled by default, but something else is already using it. Check for running software that uses virtualization, like:

- Hyper-V
- Docker for Windows
- Android emulators

Comment: I had Bluestacks installed, just that, not even open. So I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was toggling Hyper-V (on-off), then running the following as an admin in command prompt:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```